# Refrescar DIV despues de enviar modelo desde controlador Spring

Tags: javascript, ajax, mvc, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Verán, estoy trabajando con spring y thymeleaf y apenas soy un principiante en este tema; tengo el siguiente tree el cual contiene unos módulos y a su lado esta un formulario con el cual se pueden crear y editar los módulos.
[image: tree y formulario]
mi problema es que cuando deseo editar un modulo quiero que se rellenen los campos del formulario al hacer clic en uno de los elementos del `tree`; tengo el siguiente `ajax` con el cual le envió a mi `controller` el id del modulo para realizar la búsqueda en la base de datos:

```
function rellenarModulo() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/creadorRellenar",
       data: {
            idModulo: idNodo
       },
       success: function(data) {}
    });    
}
```

y en mi controller lo siguiente:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/creadorRellenar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getModulo(@ModelAttribute Modulo mod, Model model) {
    int idModuloSeleccionado = mod.getIdModulo();
    Modulo modulo = adminService.getModuloById(idModuloSeleccionado).get(0);
    System.out.println(modulo.getNombreModulo()+" 
    "+modulo.getDescripcionModulo());
    model.addAttribute("moduloss",modulo);
    return "creador";
}
```

Los datos se envian correctamente a la vista; pero sin embargo no se muestran en pantalla; solo pude comprobarlo de la siguiente manera:

[image]